# svg animate begin on previous using prev.end

Tags: svg, path, svg-animate

I wanted to animate some paths one after another automatically using animate's begin attribute:

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    version="1.1"
    width="500"
    height="500"
    viewBox="0 0 20 20">

    <path d="M10,10 m0,-5 a5,5 0 0,1 5,5 a5,5 0 0,1 -5,5 a5,5 0 0,1 -5,-5 a5,5 0 0,1 5,-5 z" fill="green">
        <animate attributeName="fill" from="green" to="white" begin="0s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
        <animate attributeName="fill" from="white" to="blue" begin="prev.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
    </path>
</svg>
```

But it seems that the prev.end on the second animation is not working. When I rewrite the animations as below and refer to the first one by ID, it does work.

```
<animate id="first" 
 attributeName="fill" 
 from="green" 
 to="white" 
 begin="0s" 
 dur="1s" 
 fill="freeze" />

<animate 
 attributeName="fill" 
 from="white" 
 to="blue" 
 begin="first.end" 
 dur="1s" 
 fill="freeze" />
```

The reason I would like to use prev.end to sync my animations, is because I am generating these animations automatically in JavaScript. Number and order of animations are variable, which makes the use of IDs more difficult for me.

Comment: ids is the only solution. if the first animation had id='prev' it would work.

Comment: I see now that this function was removed in svg 1.1. It appears that prev.end was usable in svg 1.0 (https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20000802/animate.html#TimingAttributes)